# How to close FragmentActivity android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I created an aplication in Android. I have:

- 2 Activity:

  - SplashScreen(With Logo)
  - LoginActivity(Here, I replace with my LoginFragmente(I call the xml (Login)))
- 1 FragmentActivity:

  - WelcomeFragment(Here, I recharge a navegation drawer).

In WelcomeFragment I have 3 options,when the user wants to close the session if the user wants to keep its account in the application for a next access, if he wants to keep then the application will exit but if he does not want to keep its session then he will return a Login(Xml).

My doubt is how to close android application depending of the selection of user?

Comment: You can use the shared Preference to keep the session, If you want the session to be stored then add the login credentials to the shared preference and set to be logged, If you dont want the session to be used for next access then unset the status. Based on this you can navigate your Fragments/Screens correspondingly.

Comment: I use the shared Preferences my doubt is how would my application close as I did it ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite understand what you are trying to mean in the above comment.

Comment: Sorry, how to close my application in this case?

Comment: On click of the button save the preferences in the editor and finish the activity. Which will eventfully close the application. And on Opening the application again in the OnCreate of your application check for the status of the preference and accordingly change your fragment. Hope you have fair working knowledge with shared Preference.